# Preload Ecto Association on Insert

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

For a multi tenancy eCommerce application, I have given the following ER schema:

```
Order has_many OrderProduct belongs_to Product belongs_to Price
```

With Ecto, it would be easy to insert an *Order* with many *OrderProduct* at once via `cast_assoc(:order_product)` in the changeset function of *Order*.

But since a *Product* and also a *Price* may be deleted in the future, I would like to additionally store the value of *Price* and a quantity in *OrderProducts* (`:price`, `:quantity`).

As far is I know I would have the following options to do that:

1. In the changeset function of *OrderProduct* I could fetch *Product* and join *Price* by the ID of *Product* and add `:price` of *Price* as change to *OrderProduct*. This would result in N+1 queries, since I have to execute that query for every *OrderProduct* in *Order* (which would be ok in this case since I have only a limited number of *Products* per *Order*). But furthermore, I would prefer keeping out the Repo of the schema definition module. But most importantly: I am using different schemas in my multi tenancy setup so I need to know the `prefix` in the changeset function of *OrderProduct* to execute the query on the correct `prefix`.
2. Iterate *OrderProducts* outside of the schema definitions in my `Orders` module and add `:price` as change to *OrderProduct* changeset:

```
%Order{} 
|> Order.changeset(attrs)
|> iterate_order_products_and_map_price_change(tenant)
|> Repo.insert(prefix: tenant)
```

3. Use `Ecto.Multi` where the order is inserted first and then I add the relationships with an extra `Ecto.Multi.run`

I would prefer the first option since it seems to me that this would be the cleanest approach to do that.

- Are there any other or better options for this scenario?
- Would it be possible to preload via join *Product* and *Price* for *OrderProduct* on an insert outside of the schema as well? Then I wouldn't have the `N+1` in 1.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ecto.Changeset.prepare_changes/2` is another option and probably the one you are looking for: https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#prepare_changes/2

Comment: Thanks José, this is good to know but `Ecto.Changeset.prepare_changes/2` is only run before emitting changes to the repository. Since I am also using `Ecto.Changeset.apply_action(changeset, :insert)` instead of `Repo.insert/1` in a first step to emulate the insert, `Ecto.Changeset.prepare_changes/2` is not executed (to show the shopping cart again to the customer as a validation step before finally inserting it to the database in an extra step).

Comment: Maybe you could do this: if you are going to insert it in the DB, pass the updating function to prepare_changes, if you want to show it to the user before, you call the updating function directly. It should not be a problem, since you need to call apply_action anyway, you can do both together and encapsulate that in a function.

Comment: Finally I ended up with this approach, thanks a lot!

`
%Order{} |> change_order(params) |> prepare_changes(&change_order_products(&1, tenant)) |> ... |> Repo.insert(prefix: tenant)
`